Fill an array with matrices along thr k-th diagonal
Is there an elegant way or function to fill a square 2D-array along its k-th diagonal with sub-matrices?
I am looking for something similar to what scpiy.linalg.block_diag() does but for lets say the first "diagonal" above the main "diagonal".
I am trying to fill an array like here:

where each of the elements in H is a 8x8 matrix itself.
H is an 16nx16n array, where n a natural number.
I have already filled the diagonal with the already mentioned method

H = sc.linalg.block_diag(h_bulk_plane + hS_upper,*[h_bulk_plane]*(2*(n-1)), h_bulk_plane - hS_upper)


But I can't find a good way to fill its upper/lower diagonal.

Did you look at the code for block_diagonal? I supect it is python, and may be adapted for your needs.

What you can observe is, that on the main diagonal the indices have the shape i,i. For the case of the k-th diagonal, you can just take the size like 8 for 8x8 matrices and decide if its above the main diagonal or not. Take the first index like (i,0) or (0, i) and iterate by just adding 1 to both coordinates until one of the values is >= to the size.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


I can't find a good way to fill its upper/lower diagonal.

I don't know whether you consider this a good way; anyway, the upper/lower diagonal is the main diagonal of the upper right and the lower left partial matrix, respectively (each one block row and one block column smaller). Knowing this and knowing that the non-diagonal blocks of H are zero after initialization with sc.linalg.block_diag, we can literally add the upper/lower diagonals after also having constructed their partial matrixes with sc.linalg.block_diag. If e. g. these are stored as Hud and Hld, this is done by
H[:-8, 8:] += Hud
H[8:, :-8] += Hld

